# Access VBA Stopped showing ActiveControl Is the focused control

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a bit of an oddball problem. I use a routine to check focus; and ... it stopped working. I have no idea how or why.

The routine basically checks to see if the active control is the one you're checking, and if so, returns true (so we can handle the cases where it's not).

However...it recently started returning false all the time (we didn't change anything, we only noticed when some field auditing started returning weird values). Even when the control is focused, and if there's no other controls on the form, or only one form open, and the form clearly has focus.

Does anyone have any ideas how or why this might be? It's confounding me. As you can see, I've got  a test field, where we're running an init in it...and the values clearly match, name, values, every field compared, and it still doesn't return true.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: forgot to add the code.
The whole thing as-is:

```
' I call it from here: 
' Inside form, any control, say `PurchaseCostBox`

Private Sub PurchaseCostBox_AfterUpdate()
    ' Check if the focus is had
    If VerifyFocus(Me.PurchaseCostBox) Then
        ' Save more field info.
        Debug.Print Me.PurchaseCostBox.SelStart
        Debug.Print Me.PurchaseCostBox.SelLen
        Debug.Print Me.PurchaseCostBox.Value
    Else
        ' Do limited stuff
        Debug.Print Me.PurchaseCostBox.Value
    End if
End Sub

Public Function VerifyFocus(ByRef ctlWithFocus As Control) As Boolean

    Dim FrmParent As Form
    Dim ctlCurrentFocus As Control
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Determine parent form for control
    
    ' Verify focus of parent form
    Set FrmParent = Screen.ActiveForm
    
    ' Verify focus of control on form
  
    Set ctlCurrentFocus = FrmParent.ActiveControl
    If Not ctlCurrentFocus Is ctlWithFocus Then
        ctlWithFocus.SetFocus
        DoEvents
    End If
    ' Even adding the below line does not return true:
    ctlWithFocus.SetFocus

    ' Return true if the control currently has the focus
    VerifyFocus = FrmParent.ActiveControl Is ctlWithFocus
    
    ' Discard any errors
    Err.Clear
    
End Function
```

I've also had it try this:

```
Public Function VerifyFocus(ByRef ctlWithFocus As Control) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    ' Return true if the control currently has the focus
    VerifyFocus = Screen.ActiveControl Is ctlWithFocus
    
    ' Discard any errors
    Err.Clear
    
End Function
```

Neither work any more...and I'm floundering.

[image]
[image: ControlWithFocus]

Comment: Where are you calling VerifyFocus from? Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Have you introduced a timer form? Timer forms when they trigger wind up stealing the focus for a short time - so, do check if you introduced a timer form.

Comment: @KenWhite: updated with how I call it.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: I do have a timer in the form, I'll check to see if turning it off allows the focus to be kept; but the Field NEVER returns true, not just when the timer is triggered. As you can see, the `FrmParent.ActiveControl Is ctlWithFocus` always returns false, even when they clearly match.

Comment: I turned off all timers, there's only one form open, and the result is the same: always returns no focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this turned out to be something utterly unexpected, and totally unrelated to the focus.

Turns out, one of the ways I call this is by getting a control's parent, by using `Control.Properties.Parent.Form`. While this DOES return the correct form, it also makes the above `VerifyFocus` routine never return true, ever (even when it's not being used). I don't know why. I really, at this point, don't care. But I'm going to leave it here for others to find.

Refactoring my `GetTopForm` routines allowed me to get the focus.